# Adding a JSON Selection directory to Angular Application

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, dropdown

So I'm designing a program that lets a user send a JSON to an API using HTTP-Post. 
The Json are stored in a folder inside my application called `JsonFiles` then inside this folder are then put into there own brand name so the path looks something like this  `>JsonFiles>Nike>OrderConfirm.Json`
What would be a good way to let the user select a JSON File from the user interface in like a dropdown menu?

What I have so far is being able to pick a specific file from the component.ts using import,
but this is no good due to I need user interaction to choose the file. In case anyone is wondering I'm creating an application for work.
Thanks guys so much.

Comment: Do you have any sample server-side code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can move these json files to the assets folder. So it will be available to fetch using http request.

```
httpClient.get(`/JsonFiles/Nike/${jsonFileName}.json`)
```

And in the component you just need to keep the file names.

```
files = ['OrderConfirm']
```

You can also just keep your folder anywhere, But add that path to angular.json as follows,

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.ico"
]
```

For ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Comment: Mate your a legend, This clears things up for me alot, ill just need to a way for the users to select the file and change the value of the json which is something I already worked out, Thanks very much Anto,

Comment: I Did but it wont publicly change because I'm new , you need 15 reputation hahaha